# Paste value to a range of cells the user has selected, sometimes blanks in between cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run a macro that copies a date in multiple selected cells, sometimes they are a range but other times individual cells maybe selected.  All cells will be in the same column. I recorded a macro that does this but copies in the same range or cells every time.  I want it to copy into the cells I select - which will be different every time.

Here is the code

```
Macro1 Macro
' Test copy range
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
'
    Range("$AD$10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C10").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=7
    Range("C10,C12,C16:C21").Select
    Range("C16").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

I hardly recommend this but if you want to paste it in the current selection then try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("$AD$10").Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

If you use the above method then ensure that you do proper error handling.

Alternatively use an `InputBox()` to select your range and paste it in that. See this example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Ret = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a range where you want to paste", Type:=8)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not Ret Is Nothing Then
            .Range("$AD$10").Copy

            Ret.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]